# how can i switch the side of a menu dynamically in ionic2-angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

i'm using ion-menu with sideMenu = left or right inside the class , it change when we change the language.
the sideMenu variable change but i don't know why the side menu don't .

```
<ion-menu [content]="mifonMenu"
          [side]="sideMenu"
          >
```

i also try another syntax : `[attr.side]="isRtl?'right':'left'"`

it woks, but when i change the side menu to right : and i open the menu : it start coming from end of left to the right and when i close it : it do the inverse.
but if i add `type="push"` it not works.

hope anyone can help me .

Answer (score 1):

Switching the side menu dynamically is not yet supported (there're a few open issues related to this) but you can achieve the same by adding two side menus, one in the right and one in the left

```
<ion-menu [content]="mifonMenu" id="left-menu" side="left">...</ion-menu>
```

and

```
<ion-menu [content]="mifonMenu" id="right-menu" side="right">...</ion-menu>
```

And then in the code, enable one of them according to the selected language:

```
import { MenuController, ...';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

    constructor(private menuCtrl: MenuController, ...) {}

    public yourMethod(): void {
        if (this.selectedLanguage.rtl) {
            this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'right-menu');
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'left-menu');
        } else {
            this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'right-menu');
            this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'left-menu');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i know this method, but i don't want to replicate my code . that's it ,, but in the end if i don't find a solution i will do this .
any way . thanks for your response :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but seems to be the only way for now. You can follow the status of this feature in [this git issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10074) and all the rtl-related issues [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11211).